# _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:

Tags: python

I have done fairly extensive searching but cannot find a workable solution for me. In short I have a Python GUI which user Tkinter, this runs in the Python environment perfectly fine. Now, if I freeze this and try to use it outside of my machine it fails to run reporting:

```
C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\testprogram>testprogram.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testprogram.py", line 842, in <module>
  File "lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1810, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Users/charlie/Desktop/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/charlie/Desktop/lib/tcl8.5 
C:/Users/charlie/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/charlie/Desktop/library 
C:/Users/charlie/library C:/Users/charlie/tcl8.5.15/library 
C:/Users/tcl8.5.15/library
```

I am using the pyinstaller v3.3.1 (Python 2.7 32bit Windows7) with the command line

pyinstaller --icon "testprogram.ico" --onefile -c --clean --add-data files;files testprogram.py

Everything completes fine. Except it doesn't run and complains of the above. If I freeze using --onedir instead I get the same problem. The directories that exist within the build directory are tcl and tk.

It seems to be trying to find the tcl files from outside the working directory for some reason rather than within 'testprogram'. To get the exe to work on another machine I have to copy the relavent tcl stuff to one of the above directories - or make the directory and copy the contents over.

Help appreciated on getting around this. I need to build this as one exe file.
Thanks